# How to get resource file from dependent artifact

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I want to get the resource file from dependency and put it to my classpath or another directory. I tried maven-dependency-plugin but it seems I've not configured it properly. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
         <execution>
         <id>get browsers.xml</id>
         <goals>
             <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
         </goals>
         <phase>generate-resources</phase>
         <configuration>
               <includeGroupIds>ru.fad.autotests</includeGroupIds>
               <includeArtifactIds>selenium-grid-browsers-local</includeArtifactIds>
               <includes>browsers.xml</includes>
               <outputDirectory>resources/</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
         </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I have the file 'browsers.xml' in another artifact and want to copy it to my directory.

Comment: Please share the exact code and elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you mean by "copy it to my directory?" Which directory in your project structure?  Also, "but it seems I've not configured it properly" - can you elaborate on that? What is it doing currently (errors?) compared to what you want it to do?

Comment: My file 'browsers.xml' is in dependent artifact's resources. I have to copy it into src/main/resources directory. I'm not receiving any errors. But this configuration copies meta-pom.xml besides the browsers.xml to target directory. I don't know why:) How can do it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to solve this, but I think the solution that will work best is using [Maven Build Helper](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) specifically the [`build-helper:add-resource`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) goal.

Rather than unpacking your dependencies to `resources/` (which should be version-controlled-only files), unpack your desired artifact to `target/`, i.e. `target/my-resources/` and reference that directory from build-helper.